# Optimal way for formatting floor function/fraction in upper summation limit

Tags: formatting, fractions

I am looking for the best way to format fractions in the upper limit of summations.  In particular, the fraction is the argument of the floor function.

In the following example, the floor function and fraction appear disproportionately large.

```
\begin{equation}  
\sum_{k=1}^{\left \lfloor{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right \rfloor}\frac{1}{2k-1}
\end{equation}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to achieve this result...

Comment: It's inappropriate here to use `\left` and `\right` to autosize the symbols generated by `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`, respectively. Omit `\left` and `\right` and you'll be fine...

Comment: Well I'm not sure it is the floor function that is causing the problem, it seems to me that the fraction is inherently too large and the floor function symbols are just sizing accordingly.  But it is not that the floor function itself is causing the problem, at least that is the way it seems to me.  Should I be using something other than \frac ? I have yet to try Zarko's suggestion.

Comment: If you're concerned about the size of the `\frac` expression in the upper limit of summation, you could write `\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor}`. That way, the symbols in the lower and upper limits are typeset at the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `mathtools` provide macro `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` which can be handy in your case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{ \Floor{ \frac{n+1}{2} } } \frac{1}{2k-1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `Floor` you can select name more appropriate to your taste/needs.